# How to pass kotlin class or kotlin class instance as arguments

Tags: java, kotlin

see following code:

```
class Ex() {
    fun m(i: Object) {
    }
}

class Ex2() {
    fun m2() {
        Ex().m(this)
    }    
}
```

How to make Ex#m receive Ex2 instance, I now can pass this.javaClass as arguments, but it's too trouble, what is "this"'s Class

**update**

change `fun m(i: Object)` to `fun m(i: Ex2)` can fix current example, but I hope KotlinObjectClass to make Ex#m receive variable type argument

**update**
use `Any` can fix "variable type" question, but I hope more exactly, I hope receive type only KotlinClassObjectInstance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There is no type that describes only instances of classes written in Kotlin.

Comment: @yole I hope to know "this"'s class

Comment: You can `i.javaClass` to find out the class of any object.

Comment: please edit the question by incorporating the updates into it. In the current state it is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: It would help if your example used better class names that aren't so short and similar.

Comment: This question is not useful WITHOUT KNOWING what you will do with the instance that is being received.  You give no indication of what method `m()` does with the instance it receives.  Without that you leave everyone guessing as to the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**reified type parameters**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) like so:

```
class Ex() {
    inline fun <reified T> m() {
        println(T::class)
    }
}

class Ex2() {
    fun m2() {
        Ex().m<Ex2>()
    }
}
```

Now `Ex2().m2()` will print `class Ex2`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
interface MyKotlin
class Ex {
  fun m(i: MyKotlin) {
  }
}
class Ex2 : MyKotlin {
  fun m2() {
    Ex().m(this)
  }
}
class Ex3 : MyKotlin {
  fun m3() {
    Ex().m(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: no, as what "update" say, this way may thing more complex

Comment: instead of updates, rewrite the question to be clear.  we don't need revision history in the question, it is hard to follow.  Just create a more complete sample code.